# Перенаправление в htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Добрый день!

Подскажите, пожалуйста. Как реализовать перенаправление в `htaccess` с одного адреса страницы (stranica.html%CA%EB%E5%E2%E5%F0) на страницу только без символов после html (stranica.html).

Answer (score 1):

Наверное как то так:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*stranica\.html)(.*)$ /$1? [L,NE,R=301]
```